# Proof the number of expected node in a binary using mathematical induction

Tags: binary-trees, induction, mathematical-foundations

> The following algorithm constructs a binary tree.

```
MakeArray(array[x:y]) (
 if(x==y):
  the root is x
 else: 
  pick a number r as root
  MakeArray(array[x:r-1])
  MakeArray(array[r+1:y])
)
```

> Let $a_n$ be the expected number of nodes which have two children in the tree with $n$ nodes generated.
>
> Prove $a_n = \frac{n-2}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(a_{i}+a_{n-i-1})$ using mathematical induction.

I have no idea where to start as I don't even know how to construct a proper equation to carry on the proof. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with linearity of expectation?

Comment: no, I have not learnt about it

Comment: You will not be able to solve this without using linearity of expectation.

Comment: I just googled. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linearity-of-expectation/

Comment: I am not sure how I can apply to this question

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I think I know where does $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(a_{i}+a_{n-i-1})$ come from. But may I know why n-2 instead of n -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array has length $n = 1$ then the constructed tree consists just of a root. Therefore $a_1 = 0$. Similarly, $a_0 = 0$ (this is a corner case).

Now suppose that $n \geq 2$. Without loss of generality, assume that $x = 1$, and so $y = n$. The array splits into two halves: $1,\ldots,r-1$ and $r+1,\ldots,n$. The first has length $r-1$, and the second has length $n-r$. If $r = 1$ or $r = n$, the one of these halves is empty; this happens with probability $\frac{2}{n}$. So with probability $\frac{n-2}{n}$, the root has two children. Defining $i = r-1$, we see that $i$ is chosen uniformly among the $n$ options $0,\ldots,n-1$, and the two subarrays have lengths $i,n-1-i$. From here it is straightforward to deduce your formula, using linearity of expectation.

Your formula simplifies to
$$
a_n = \frac{n-2}{n} + \frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i.
$$
This implies that
$$
(n+1)a_{n+1} - na_n = n-1 + 2 \sum_{i=0}^n a_i - (n-2) - 2 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i = 1 + 2a_n,
$$
and so
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{n+2}{n+1} a_n + \frac{1}{n+1} \Longrightarrow a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{a_n}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1}.
$$
Now
\begin{multline}
a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} = \frac{a_{n+1}}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+2} = \frac{a_n}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{n+2} =\\ \frac{a_n}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1} = a_{n+1} - a_n.
\end{multline}
In other words, $a_n$ is an arithmetic progression. You can check that $a_n = \frac{n-2}{3}$ for $n \geq 2$.